# Help With Speeding Up Nested Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below select query I perform, however it is alarmingly slow against even ~6000 records and am curious if there is an alternate way to build the query?

```
select sum(Q.R) 
from (select 
        T.drawing_no,
        max(T.drawing_rev),
        T.R 
      from (select 
              drawing_no,
              drawing_rev,
              sum(price_total) as R 
            from data_pipe_drawing 
            where drawing_status="IP" 
            group by 
              drawing_no,
              drawing_rev) as T 
      group by T.drawing_no) as Q
```

In English the query finds all the drawings with a status of IP, rolls up the prices (price_total) by drawing_no+drawing_rev and then returns only the price_total of the highest revision for each drawing and rolls it all up for a grand price_total.

Thus before hitting the max(T.drawing_rev) if the query held:

```
 Drawing A Rev 1 Total Cost $100
 Drawing A Rev 0 Total Cost $50
 Drawing B Rev 0 Total Cost $200
```

The Drawing A Rev 0 is dropped from the grand total. The grand total is $300.

Hope this makes sense... thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does MySQL ***guarantee*** that the `T.R` value is associated with the record that gave `MAX(t.drawing_rev)`?  I'm no MySQL expert, but selecting `T.R` without grouping by it just gives me the willies...

Comment: Have you tried decomposing it to use temporal tables instead? Make each nested query put its results into a temporal table and run the next query on such table, etc. See how that performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I don't feel safe with the query you wrote, I'd do something with a correlated sub-query, like this...

```
  SELECT
--  drawing_no,
    SUM(price_total)
  FROM
    data_pipe_drawing AS data
  WHERE
    drawing_status="IP" 
    AND drawing_rev = (SELECT MAX(drawing_rev) FROM data_pipe_drawing WHERE drawing_status = "IP" AND drawing_no = data.drawing_no)
--GROUP BY
--  drawing_no

-- Commented lines useful for testing individual drawings
```

Then have an index on `(drawing_status, drawing_no, drawing_rev)`

Or possibly even this...

```
  SELECT
    SUM(data.price_total)
  FROM
    data_pipe_drawing AS data
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      drawing_status,
      drawing_no,
      MAX(drawing_rev) AS drawing_rev
    FROM
      data_pipe_drawing
    GROUP BY
      drawing_status,
      drawing_no
  )
    AS lookup
      ON  lookup.drawing_number = data.drawing_number
      AND lookup.drawing_rev    = data.drawing_rev
      AND lookup.drawing_status = data.drawing_status
  WHERE
    data.drawing_status="IP"
```

**EDIT**

Changed the JOIN based solution to possibly be friendlier for multiple drawing states, pending mor einfor from the OP.

Comment: Thanks Dems, definitely works and is far more readable... seems to give the same figures but is still quite slow (upwards of 1.5 minutes) =(  I'm wondering if there's a bigger issue in my setup

Comment: It should be noted I perform this same query against 5 different drawing_status values, so this time stacks up huge...

Comment: My only tips are...  1. Ensure you have the index I mentioned.  2. Test with `rev = 0` instead of the correlated sub-query in my example.  (If it's slow with `= 0` instead of a sub-query, it's just going to be slow.)  [When you say you do this for 5 states, could you elaborate in an edit to the question?  Can one drawing_no have different states in different rows, how should the stated be handled, etc.  Sample data of the real situation helps :)]

Comment: Thanks! Missed the part about the index... your first solution is now instantaneous.  I tested the second solution before applying the index and it felt just as fast (impressive).

Answer (score 0):

Try seperating your query with temporary table,

```
create temporary table tmp_table select 
              drawing_no,
              drawing_rev,
              sum(price_total) as R 
            from data_pipe_drawing 
            where drawing_status="IP" 
            group by 
              drawing_no,
              drawing_rev;

select sum(Q.R) 
from (select 
        T.drawing_no,
        max(T.drawing_rev),
        T.R 
      from tmp_table T 
      group by T.drawing_no) as Q
```